# Trouble with array in for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I would like my program to generate the Fibonacci sequence with a few adjustments to be made by the user.

After entering how many numbers they would like to generate, the user will input the amount of *modifiers* they would like to enter.

I understand that this means an array of dimension `n`, will need to be created, where `n` is the number of modifiers the user would like to input. (i.e. between 10-20 the numbers are multiplied by 2, between 21-30 the numbers will be multiplied by 3, etc.)

Next, the user will input the intervals they would like to adjust. (i.e. between Fibonacci numbers 10-20, 21-30, 31-40, etc.)

My problem arises when i run the interval checking loop. It doesn't work for me to put:

```
for (intervalarray[n][0] < n < intervalarray[n][1]) { /* ... */ }
```

So I am assuming I will need a *pointer* to the array. But I'm not finding any helpful tutorials regarding this issue.

I'm new to C++ so please be patient and if you can't directly answer my question please point me in a direction to study to help me find a solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int newnumb, thisnumb, lastnumb, runtotal, yourup;
int i, n;
float yourbet;

int s, t;

int getnumbers() {
    cout << "how many numbers would you like to generate?";
    cin >> n;
}

int main() {
    /* Ask the user how many numbers of the Fib Sequence to generate,
       store the answer in the variable 'n' */

    getnumbers();

    cout << "How many modifiers are there? \n";
    cin >> s;

    float justtesting[s][3];

    /* This loop is going to use a variable j to span the array by rows,
       (i.e. j < the number of rows), storing the values into the array of dim(s) */

    cout << "When does the first modified interval begin?" << endl;
    cin >> justtesting[0][0];

    cout << "When does that modified interval end?" << endl;
    cin >> justtesting[0][1];

    for (int j = 1; j < s; j++) {
        cout << "When does the next modified interval begin?" << endl;
        cin >> justtesting[j][0];

        cout << "When does that modified interval end?" << endl;
        cin >> justtesting[j][1];
    }

    /* This loop is going to take the modifier divisor values and store them in
       the third dimensional slot of each row of the array */

    cout << endl;
    cout << "What is the first divisor?" << endl;
    cin >> justtesting[0][2];

    for (int l = 1; l < s; l++) {
        cout << "What is the next divisor?" << endl;
        cin >> justtesting[l][2];
    }

    cout << endl;

    /* Prints out user input values for the intervals to be modified */

    for (int row = 0; row < s; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 2; column++) {
            cout << justtesting[row][column] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "  " << endl;

    /* Prints out the divisors that were stored in the 3rd dimension of
       the user generated array */

    for (int row = 0; row < s; row++) {
        cout << justtesting[row][2] << " ";
    }

    // Loop for fib sequence

    thisnumb = 1;
    lastnumb = 0;
    runtotal = 0;
    yourup   = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
        newnumb = thisnumb + lastnumb;
        yourup = 2 * lastnumb - runtotal;

        thisnumb = lastnumb;
        lastnumb = newnumb;
        runtotal = (thisnumb + lastnumb) - 1;

        cout << "The count: " << i ;
        cout << " Fibornacci Number: " << thisnumb;
```

Comment: Please use paragraphs in your problem statement as it is hard to read. Please indent your code properly.

Comment: `for (intervalarray[n][0] < n < intervalarray[n][1])` isn't valid syntax.  It isn't clear which for loop you're having trouble with or where it is in the code you posted which appears to be cut off at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for how to implement what's known as a "ragged array" or "dynamic array"  You're going to be comparing numbers to each other for an unknown (to the program) number of integers.  If you're letting them be input by users.

It looks like you'll need to learn how to use the `new` and `delete` keywords.